# How could I create a toggle with change of class to open and to close

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How could I create a toggle with change of class to open and to close.
When the menu is opened the scroll of the body should be disabled.

Ex:

```
.menu{
background: #000;
}

.menu-show{
display: block;
}

.menu-hidden{
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any solutions yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use JQuery to make it easy**

```
var i=1;
    function toggleMenu()
    {
    if(i==1) // show it
    {
    $("#menu").removeClass("menu-hide");
    $("#menu").addClass("menu-show");
    $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
    i++;
    }
    else // hide it
    {
    $("#menu").removeClass("menu-show");
    $("#menu").addClass("menu-hide");
    $("body").css("overflow","auto");
    i=1;
    }
    }
```

**Call this function by onclick**

```
<button onclick="toggleMenu()">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will you be able to use this way:

Will you be able to use this way:

```
.menu {background: red; display: none;}
.menu.open {display: block;}
```

And in the jQuery, you can toggle it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".trigger").click(function () {
        $(".menu").toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery it's rather simple.

```
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
   $('.menu').toggle();
});
```

The toggle function toggles between show and hide. There's a couple different methods you can use to achieve what you're going for, just depends on which best suits you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap who has done great work around this idea.

Have a look at  [Bootstrap Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

It while simplify your life even if of course it is important for you to learn how to do that aswell in proper code.

Haa and by the way : Welcome to StackOverflow ;)